# Ruby get value by array index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning RubyonRails and I am coming from the background of PHP

I have an array that looks like this

```
TYPES = [
  'Casual' => 'casual',
  'Full-Time' => 'full_time',
  'Part-Time' => 'part_time',
]
```

I want to get the value of index `Casual` and this is what I am doing to get it

```
work_type = TYPES.first['Casual']
```

Although it works perfectly fine and I am able to get the value but I am wondering if this is the right way to do it and if I should be using `map`

Comment: You can't have an array that looks like that. That is invalid.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You're right.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Is the OP's description correct Hash literal in PHP? If it is, it should be written that the literal is in PHP. Otherwise, the background does not matter.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Then the question really does not make sense. I can still edit to try to make it make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145347/discussion-between-sergio-tulentsev-and-sawa).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, this is not the right way, and no, you shouldn't be using map. Rather, you should forget that horrible abomination that PHP calls "associative arrays".

Ruby has proper dictionaries/hashmaps, you want to use them here:

```
TYPES = {
  'Casual' => 'casual',
  'Full-Time' => 'full_time',
  'Part-Time' => 'part_time',
}

TYPES['Casual'] # => 'casual'
```

Comment: Yes I tried this at first and that gives me an error of TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Comment: @Saadia: note the different brackets

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an `Array` of `Hash`

```
TYPES = [{
  'Casual' => 'casual',
  'Full-Time' => 'full_time',
  'Part-Time' => 'part_time',
}]
```

And yes, you can use `first` if you have only one hash inside the `Array`

But if you have more than two `Hash` and you want to collect all the values of `Casual` go with `map`

```
work_types = TYPES.map { |type| type['Casual'] }
#=> ["casual", "something else"]
```

**EDIT**

**If you do have a single hash then I will suggest you use @sergio' s answer**